# How can I redirect HTTP requests to use HTTPS?

Tags: windows, http, https, hosts-file

Is it possible to automatically redirect HTTP to HTTPS?

Can I amend my host file in such a way that when I visit http://www.hsbc.co.uk it will redirect me to https://www.hsbc.co.uk? or is there another way to achieve this.

Comment: Similar: http://superuser.com/questions/150632/force-a-browser-to-load-the-https-edition-of-a-website-not-the-http and http://superuser.com/questions/176217/block-access-to-a-website-via-http-but-not-https-via-etc-hosts

Answer (score 4):

[HTTPS Everywhere](http://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) is a good start, if you want a custom brew solution then use [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/) to rewrite URLs.

Please note that the `hosts` file is to give domains a new IP and only just that...

Answer (score 1):

HTTP and HTTPS are different protocols. Your hosts file (or DNS) does not determine what protocol is used.