# Force browser to use HTTPS only?

Tags: browser, https

Is there some way to force a popular desktop browser (IE, Chrome, Firefox, Opera etc.) to only connect to a site via HTTPS and if the site does not support HTTPS, then not connect at all?

Comment: Are you saying you don't want to use Stack Exchange? :)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling SU has https :p

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force a browser to load the 'https' edition of a website, not the 'http'?](http://superuser.com/questions/150632/), [Force web address to go through HTTPS](http://superuser.com/questions/1501/), [How can I redirect HTTP requests to use HTTPS?](http://superuser.com/questions/338564/)

Comment: @and31415 As far as I can tell, this question is not a duplicate of either of those. Here, the OP wants non-HTTPS sites to *fail to load*, which is an important distinction not included in the answers to the possible duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

To redirect connection to the https version of the site, there are many extensions out there like [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere).

Now on to fail the connection if only http and no https is found, you may use [Privoxy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ijbswa/files/) and set this blacklist rule in one of the action files you would like to use:

{ +block }
http://.*

This will block all requests that has "http://" line, but not "https://". For sure though, you will encounter a lot problems displaying sites in general.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about other browsers, but for FireFox there is [HTTP Nowhere](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/http-nowhere). I just installed and tested it, and it seems to do exactly what you want.

**EDIT**
I don't have a copy of Google Chrome to test it with, but [Force HTTPS Security](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/force-https-security) would do what you want if the name is telling the truth.